# Why is the html script not getting the list from my code.gs file

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a youtube sort of thingy but I've been testing it and it doesn't paste the youtube titles into the custom dialog. I have 2 files. `Code.gs` and `youtube.html`. Here are the files

**Code.gs**

```
function youtube(input1){
  const list = []
  const sr = YouTube.Search.list("snippet", {q: input1, maxResults: 50})
  sr.items.forEach(function(vid){
    list.push(vid.snippet.title)
  })
  return list
}
```

**youtube.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="printData()">Return</button>
    <script>
      function printData(){
        const list = google.script.run.youtube("test")
        document.write(list)
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run it, it just does nothing when I click the button

Comment: You need to use the success handler to catch the return from server function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
      function printData(){
        const list = google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler((list) => document.write(list))
        .youtube("test")
      }
</script>
```

[success handler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers)